# What does appending two lists like this return one list rather than a cons cell of two lists?

Tags: list, append, scheme, lisp, cons

A common and simple way of appending two lists is as follows:

```
(define (append a b)
  (if (null? a)
      b
      (cons (car a) (append (cdr a) b))))
```

Why does this work? When we reach the final element of `a`, my clearly incorrect belief is that we will be calling `(cons [the original list a, built out of many calls to (cons (car a) ...)] [the original list b])`. In short, I can't see why function does not return `(cons a b)`, which would be a `cons` cell containing two lists. Even if I'm wrong about the `a` part, why is it valid to add `b` to our output as a whole list, without first breaking it down in to its individual elements?

I suspect that a worked example will be of great value to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere is `a` consed to `b`. Instead, the *elements* of `a` are consed to `b`, starting from the *last* element of `a`. Consider:

```
(append '() '(1 2 3))
--> '(1 2 3)  ; there are no elements in `a` to cons onto `b`

(append '(y) '(1 2 3))
--> (cons (car '(y)) (append (cdr '(y)) '(1 2 3)))
--> (cons 'y (append '() '(1 2 3)))
--> (cons 'y '(1 2 3))  ; the last element of `a` is consed onto `b`
--> '(y 1 2 3)

(append '(x y) '(1 2 3))
--> (cons (car '(x y)) (append (cdr '(x y)) '(1 2 3)))
--> (cons 'x (append '(y) '(1 2 3)))
--> (cons 'x (cons (car '(y)) (append (cdr '(y)) '(1 2 3))))
--> (cons 'x (cons 'y (append '() '(1 2 3))))
--> (cons 'x (cons 'y '(1 2 3)))  ; the last element of `a` is consed onto `b`
--> (cons 'x '(y 1 2 3))  ; then the next-to-last element of `a`, and so on
--> '(x y 1 2 3)
```

Comment: You were smarter than you ever needed to be. My error was failing to realize that `(cons [any singleton] [any list])` is obviously itself a list.